# Get the number of friends of a friend

Tags: facebook, count

I'd like to get the number of the friends of a friend. Do you know if it's possible ?
I am tempted to say yes as this information is public and disponnible on the public profile of a person.

Answer (score 3):

This is not available through the API. If you try, it will give you an error message like:

> Can't lookup all friends of (ID). Can only lookup for the logged in
>   user (ID), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate
>   permission.

You would have to break the Facebook TOS and scrape this data, and its not always publicly visible for every user.

Comment: Sorry but when you talk about TOS, you talk about the Terms of service ? You mean that if I try to retrieve this data directly on the site using a parser that would be a violation ? I am a bit disappointed not to be able to recover a data like this.

Comment: Yes, https://www.facebook.com/terms.php "You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our permission"